# Spark Logging in Cluster Mode Prints Nothing

Tags: scala, logging, apache-spark

When running in local mode this will print logs to the console:

```
object Util extends Logging {

    val df: DataFrame = ???

    df.select("id", "name")
      .rdd.foreach(r => log.warn("here"))
}
```

But when running in cluster mode, it does not.  I believe it's because the log command is executing on a worker node rather than the master.

Same thing if using `println(...)`

How can I have the log results show up in the console?

Answer (score 1):

If you run your job on a cluster, first you should `collect` your `rdd` data.

```
rdd.collect().foreach(r ⇒ log.warn("here"))
```

But possibly it is not a good idea, to collect all `rdd`, so you may use `take` function, to get the small number of rdd elements to print.

Comment: I just remembered 'collect' sends data back to the driver - so this works.  But it is not a complete solution, because sometimes we want to log intermediates that will never be sent back to the driver.

Comment: @BAR Seems to me there two possible decisions: to write to file, or to iterate over partitions, to collect rdds for each and print, what do you think?

Comment: Just remembered: to make a custom accumulator, to send only what we want to print

Comment: i was thinking a solution (probably not the simplest possible) would be to send data to an akka actor on the driver who will faithfully print received messages.

Comment: @BAR If you provide it, will be great to see.